# Phalcon + Angular. Не работает [ngRoute]

Tags: angularjs, phalcon, angular-routing

Всем привет.

Решил совместить Phalcon + Angular.
Но при переходе на другую страничку "без перезагрузки страницы" с помощью Angular[ngRoute], Phalcon выбивает ошибку "Exception: TemplateController handler class cannot be loaded" (попробовал отдельно без Phalcon все работает).

В чем суть проблемы  понимаю, но хотел бы узнать как можно это устранить.

Comment: посмотрите в devtools браузера, какой запрос реально уходит